# Multiple Helm chart and parent chart need to be executed first and complete when all sub charts are completed

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a situation where I have one parent chart called parent and 2 sub child charts called child1 and child2 (child sub charts uses different docker image from the parent chart.). I want parent chart to be executed first as it copies script from container to NFS volume and other charts i.e. child1 and child2 consume the script i.e. execute the scripts and create a status on shared NFS volume among all the pods.

Parent chart or POD keep an eye on status file and once all the status files created , it proceed further and perform some validations and execute rest of the setup steps.

Is there a way to resolve this situation?